# How to find cause for sluggish network, get data for hosting provider

Tags: networking

I am using wget to download files and on multiple servers (same provider) I get "connection closed", socket errno 4, errno 4 socket error timed out, etc.

What can I do to show the provider it's a problem on their side? Or if I am wrong, how can I find out more about the cause?

Thank you for your help, much appreciated

I tried:

- disable iptables
- check resolver.conf
- use dig to check everything ok, DNS seems to return IP for my server, authority answers OK

Comment: The provider was aware of the issue and suggested to send in: tracert, pings, traceroute, etc to inspect it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a network problem, traceroute and pings are useful high-level tools to get a feel for reliability.  If anything, a packet capture using tcpdump/wireshark will provide more details about the underlying protocol transmission.  For example, if you see a bunch of tcp retransmits, that could indicate a problem with the network (anything from the actual wires to network hardware).

If you do a packet capture, you should start from the moments leading up to the socket closing and work backwards.  Depending on how the socket is closed (which endpoint sends a rst or fin), that could also indicate whether the problem is with the network or application on either end.

Comment: Smokeping for network monitoring.

Answer (score 0):

What does your monitoring show?  If you aren't monitoring the server, that's step #1.  Are you seeing large CPU usage spikes? Large inbound traffic spikes? Large numbers of incoming HTTP requests?  You could even set up a ping to your gateway, if you see lost packets that would most likely indicate a network issue.

Without any sort of data as to how your server is performing, we can't give you any sort of meaningful answer.

Answer (score -1):

sir you do one thing,start download by wget and meanwhile u check command netstat -p tcp and show report to provider....